# What's a common decision to describe "conceding your turn in a queue to somebody else"?

Tags: phrase-request

Example sentence:

> I think I will __. Who wants it?

I thought the right phrase was "to give away your turn." But Google didn't yield many results.

Comment: Note that doing this is likely to anger the people around you in line as you're giving up your place to someone who hasn't been waiting as long. You're better off just "stepping out of line".

Comment: What we might commonly say depends on the situation. It's probably difficult to find *give up/away my turn/place* because that would seldom be someone's primary motivation in and of itself. The closest natural or idiomatic phrase to your example that comes to my mind would be something like *I think I'll give up my place.* But more context would be helpful. Consider: *I think I need to leave. Who wants my place?* *I'm not in a hurry. Would you like to go ahead of me?* Etc.

Comment: If you are staying in line, then as @JimReynolds said, "Would you like to go ahead of me?" is commonly used in the US. If you are not staying in line, just leave.

Answer (score 2):

If "queue" means a literal line of people, then the phrasal verb "let somebody in" is used in British English:

> I think I will let somebody in. Who wants it?

In a game-playing context, you might use the phrasal verb "[to give up](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/give-up?q=give+up)" your turn.